# Order all queries

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I'm creating a new chat system with ColdFusion, but I'm having a lot of trouble with sorting out a little problem.

First of all I'll explain how the system works. When creating a new chat with someone, it creates a conversation row in the MySQL table `conversations`. After that, users can send each other messages. When sending a message, a row is inserted into the table `conversations_messages` with the timestamp, the user that sent the message, the message, and of course the id of the message. Sounds logical, but now comes the big problem: organizing all those messages.

Users can view their messages with others on a page, this is the code of that page:

```
// Check conversation ID based on page url
<cfif IsDefined('URL.chat') and URL.chat neq "">

     // Load conversation based on page url
     <cfquery name = "getconv" datasource = "#DSN#">
         SELECT * 
         FROM  `conversations` 
     </cfquery>

    // Get all messages from this conversation
    <cfoutput query="getconv">
         <cfquery name = "getmessages" datasource = "#DSN#">    
             SELECT * 
             FROM  `conversations_messages` 
             WHERE  `conversation` = '#chat#'
             ORDER BY  `conversations_messages`.`id` DESC 
         </cfquery>

         // Get messages sent by 'user_one'
         <cfquery name = "my" datasource = "#DSN#"> 
              SELECT * 
              FROM  `conversations_messages` 
              WHERE  `conversation` LIKE  '#chat#'
              AND    `user` LIKE  '#user.id#'
              ORDER BY  `conversations_messages`.`id` DESC 
         </cfquery>

         // Get messages sent by 'user_two'
         <cfquery name = "friend" datasource = "#DSN#"> 
             SELECT * 
             FROM  `conversations_messages` 
             WHERE  `conversation` LIKE  '#chat#'
             AND    `user` LIKE  '#getconv.user_two#'
         </cfquery>


         <div class="content">

             // Messages sent by 'user_one' aka. user that created conversation
             You: <cfoutput><cfloop query="my">#my.message#<br></cfloop></cfoutput>

             // Messages sent by 'user_two'
             Friend: <cfoutput><cfloop query="friend">#friend.message#</cfloop></cfoutput>

            </cfoutput>
         </div>

 </cfif>
```

This is how the results show up right now: (as you can see it's sorted by user)

[image]

I want it to be sorted by message ID, so it shows up like this:

[image]

I hope it's a bit clearer now! 
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: That last paragraph is where you lost me :) Can you post a sample of the actual output - and what you would like to see instead?

Comment: (.. also, did you forget to order the second query by `conversations_messages.id DESC` ?)

Comment: Looks to me that the next step is a union query of queries between queries my and friend, ordered by the timestamp.

Comment: Forgot to order the second query, indeed. Allright, let me try to explain a bit better with some images. This is how it shows up right now: http://d.pr/i/bOeH - as you can see it's sorted by user_id. I want it to be sorted by message ID, so it shows up like this: http://d.pr/i/QSQU - i hope it's a bit clearer now!

Comment: Doing what @DanBracuk said is the answer. Not understanding your opposition to merging the two queries together together, would make it a lot easier and more than likely be faster, especially once you get a lot of messages.

Comment: What would change in the queries and in the output? I'm really new to Coldfusion, so i just tried to put some bits and pieces together to make this.

Comment: It seems to me that your query "getmessages" has what you are after. It looks to be all messages from this 'conversation = chat' ordered by 'conversations_messages.id'.  You really shouldn't query for '*' either, specify the needed columns only. You will get better performance that way.

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but just something regarding the undertaking as a whole. Are you using ColdFUsion 10? Could you possibly achieve all this via web sockets?

Comment: Just catching up. @Miguel-F's comment is the right answer to your original question. Technically Dan's suggestion would work too, but there is really no need for the extra `union` when a single query will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(not sure why everyone is answering in comments rather than as "an answer"?)

The order that your results are returned from the DB are purely down to the order you tell them to be returned. So if you want them chronologically, then don't fetch them ordered by name; order them chronologically.

So don't get user1's messages, and then user2's messages, just get the messages for the entire conversation in conversation order. Then when you're outputting them, look at which user made which comment and do the "you" / "friend" stuff.

That said, I think the approach you're taking is less than ideal. What you should perhaps be doing is fetching the messages incrementally, as they happen, rather than waiting to get all of them (if you see what I mean). So on each person's UI get all the messages since the last displayed message, and display 'em (in chronological order), then wait for some polling interval, and then fetch the next lot of messages that have occurred since the last time (etc).

If you're using ColdFusion 10 all this stuff has already been done for you via the Web Sockets technology CF has. So that would be the way to go if that's an option for you.

Comment: *fetching the messages incrementally* It is possible these queries are for some sort of "chat history" page. In which case it would make sense. Otherwise, I agree. Incremental pulls is a much better way to go.

Comment: Hi @Leigh. It could be, but the question is worded to suggest this code is for "as the chat is happening". Still: giving considerations to both situations is a good heads-up.

Comment: Yep, I suspect it is for "real-time" chat. But like you said, it is good to look at it from different perspectives.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it it now.

Answer (score 2):

(as Adam suggested here is an answer)

It seems to me that your query `getmessages` has what you are after. It looks to be all messages from this `conversation = chat` ordered by `conversations_messages.id`.

You really shouldn't query for `*` either, specify the needed columns only. You will get better performance that way.

Also, always use `<cfqueryparam>` tags in your `cfquery` blocks.

Also, you cannot nest `<cfoutput>` tags without a `group` attribute. Your code is already in a `<cfoutput>` so no need for another.

If you are on ColdFusion 10 I would definitely give @Adam's answer a look.

Comment: *you cannot nest `<cfoutput>` tags* .. and on that subject @Yannick, never run queries *inside* a loop if you can help it because you are hitting the database once for every record in the query. That is very inefficient and usually ... completely unnecessary.